# Jquery Datatable show entries and global search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable to display my data in grid form.

I also have added custom search on each column.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/x7jstfw1/5/

I want to have show entries at the top before the grid. The issue is  when I include:

```
"dom": "rtip"
```

Then the show entries does not shows up.

If I comment it, show entries does show but the global search bar also appears which I don't want to show.

I also tries with

```
searching: false
```

With this the global search does not show but my custom column search does not work.

Any workaround for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this want you are trying?

https://jsfiddle.net/x7jstfw1/15/

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
"columns": [{
    "data": "id"
  },
  {
    "data": "name"
  }
],
"dom": '<"top"l>'
```

});

refer to data-tables dom documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: I want to hide global search

Comment: Here is the updated link without search https://jsfiddle.net/x7jstfw1/15/